# "Unknown attribute" on Ruby script being run on Heroku

Tags: ruby, activerecord, heroku, migration, runtime-error

I've got a one-off script that I'm using to load some data into my application's database.

This is kind of large-ish so I've gist'd it here: https://gist.github.com/097fb5a30ce84522077a

**The code as written works flawlessly** when executing against a local Postgres instance on my local machine (or even a remote instance) as specified by the DATABASE_URL environment variable.

However, it will absolutely not work from Heroku. Executing the ruby script linked gives me this error:

```
~ $ ruby importprofiles.rb
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in assign_attributes': unknown attribute: owner_id
(ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
```

My workflow is basically:

- Create the app on Heroku (`heroku create mybot`)
- Push the code up (`git commit -m 'initial commit' && git push heroku master`)
- Set up the database (`heroku run rake db:setup`)
- Restart the instance (`heroku restart`)
- Invoke a Bash shell on the heroku instance (`heroku run bash`)
- Use Curl to pull down my production profiles.ini from a server (`curl http://blah.com/profiles.ini > profiles.ini`)
- Run the script (`ruby importprofiles.rb`)

Why am I getting unknown attribute errors on Heroku for code that works locally?

Comment: Just updated the gist with the schema.rb. I only have two migrations set up and they both ran successfully, and my local database is also PostgreSQL.

If it's at all helpful, i've got the full code up on http://github.com/Karunamon/rbreibot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `schema.rb` doesn't match your real database or you've never tried to use a `Profile` owner for anything. You have this in `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "profiles", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title",   :limit => 100
  t.integer  "owner"
  t.datetime "timeset"
  t.string   "whoset"
end
```

The `t.integer "owner"` defines a column named `owner` in the `profiles` table but you need an `owner_id` column.

Perhaps you did a manual `alter table` to rename the column in your development environment. Or maybe this is the first time you've gone along this code path.

In any case, you need a migration to rename `profiles.owner` to `profiles.owner_id`. Or, since you're just getting started, you could hand-edit `schema.rb` to rename the column and the rebuild your Heroku database. I'd just patch `schema.rb` by hand and start again if you don't have any data to worry about.

Comment: That was it! I obviously need to keep better tabs on the state of my database; really a silly mistake :)

Thanks so much!